# IE8 rotate filter rotates div but not text

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-8

I'm currently trying to rotate text on all browsers incl. ie8+. I have set up my transforms for all the other browsers, but when it comes to IE8, I can only get the box to rotate, the text will not rotate with it.

see here:
https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/106547/rotate/rotate.html

the markup:

```
<div id='container' class='container'>
<p class='rotated'>
My view has been loaded
</p>
text
</div>
```

the style:
regular -

```
.rotated{
        display: block;
        position: relative;

        /* Safari */
        -webkit-transform: rotate(-90deg);

        /* Firefox */
        -moz-transform: rotate(-90deg);

        /* IE */
        -ms-transform: rotate(-90deg);

        /* Opera */
        -o-transform: rotate(-90deg);

        transform: rotate(-90deg);



    }
```

and the IE8 conditional

```
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
<style type="text/css">
.rotated, .container{
    zoom:1;
    -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.BasicImage(rotation=3)";
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.BasicImage(rotation=3);
}
</style>
<![endif]-->
```

as you can see here, the div/paragraph tags are rotated, but the text is staying horizontal:
[image: http://f.cl.ly/items/1h3w2I1A2M3e3b1Z1B0a/rotate.jpg]

I've been poking away at this for a while and can't seem to figure out why it isn't rotating. I'm not worried about the rotation position at the moment, I'm just trying to get it to rotate. Any ideas what is wrong? 
Thanks.

Comment: Why are you rotating both `.rotated` and `.container` in IE8-specific CSS?

Comment: It was more to see if rotating only one was my issue. There's no real reason for me to do it other than testing purposes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

for older IE, you should look after `writing-mode` to rotate entire box :)

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ms531187%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Comment: Oh! Well that's quite a bit easier, and seems to suit my purpose well. Thanks! Will mark as answered once I can.

Comment: whatever , just tell us if it did it ;)

Answer (score 1):

Your IE8 style uses the following selector `.rotated, .container`, whereas your normal style only rotates `.rotated`.

This is likely to be the root cause of the problem: the IE8 style is telling the browser to try to rotate both the `container` and the `rotated` elements. Since one is inside the other, this means that it will be trying to rotate the inner element twice.

In theory, this would mean that `it would end up being upside-down, but we're dealing with IE's activeX`filter` styles here, and they are known blow up when you combine them, so given that I can understand why it would be showing the text un-rotated.

If you're doing a lot of rotating stuff in old IE, you might want to also know about the [CSS Sandpaper library](http://www.useragentman.com/blog/tag/css-sandpaper/). This is a small Javascript polyfill lib that adds support for (near-) standard `transform` CSS to old IE versions. Using this makes life a *lot* easier as you can use the same syntax for all browsers, and not have to worry about the ugly `filter` styles.

Answer (score -1):

Are you working local? Filters for Internet Explorer are only working online.